# How do I know which wildcard to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wildcard

I've been doing some reading on the documentation of `glob`, but I've gotten a bit lost on one thing. What confuses me is `fnmatch`, the documentation shows that it allows for the making of string patterns to search for, similar to `re` but with different wildcard notation.

When is an asterisk in a string a wildcard? When isn't it? Does it depend on which packages I've imported?

Do I have to import specific packages for certain purposes regarding strings, or is there some universal wildcard?

I was looking at this page [Google Python for Education](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) where it says that `\w` is a wildcard for a word character. So there is more than one wildcard? Or does that one only exist for regular expressions?

Comment: wildcard are not regexes.

Comment: I dont understand your question.   Both `fnmatch` and `re` use `*` and it is used.  Can you clarify your question more?   See:https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Comment: * wildcard is the same as `.*`. When you say wildcard, it's not regex.

Comment: "When is an asterisk in a string a wildcard? When isn't it? Does it depend on which packages I've imported?" — Are you asking when `fnmatch` treats an asterisk in a string as a wildcard, or do you somehow think that wildcardness is a part of the language independent of `fnmatch` and `re`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I hope my answer won't be too opinion based.

Wildcard notation is used by `fnmatch` and `glob` for filename matching. It has some similarities with regexes but it is different.

[wildcards](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/wildcard.html) are mainly used to match *filenames* (ex: `*.txt`, `foo-[0-9].bin`), simpler to use and also more limited.

[regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) are more powerful, can find/match/extract complex patterns. They're "overkill" and not convenient to match filenames by extension:

examples:

to match all files with `.txt` extension:

- wildcard: `*.txt`
- regex: `.*\.txt$`

to match all filenames starting by a number:

- wildcard: `[0-9]*`
- regex: `^\d.*`

to match files starting with a bearing .h or .c extension:

- wildcard: `a*.[ch]`
- regex: `^a.*\.[ch]$`

the first one is easier to grasp by a power user whereas the latter is more useful to script writers & programmers, (and also allows to extract parts, aka *groups* from the text).

You could use `fnmatch` as a poor man's regex tester for text filtering in your programs, so users familiar with file patterns will know how to use your custom filters.

read more about the differences in this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/how-do-regular-expressions-differ-from-wildcards-used-to-filter-files

Comment: Your second notation for regex is also in the `glob` documentation i was looking at, here: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)
Why is would you want there to be something like `.*\.`? Wouldn't that just imply that your folder has an extension in its name?

Comment: I don't get your question. Matching files using regexes cannot be done with `glob`. You have to iterate through the dir/files and use regex match on each. No standard module does that.